# Object(id, List) to multiple List(Objects(id,field)

Tags: scala

I have a case class

```
case class Router(routerId: String, modelInfo: List[Map[String,String]])
```

I would like to convert it to Tuple3(routerId, pinModel,color)

***modelInfo = List[Map[pinModel,color]]***

For example, If i have a Router object as:

```
val router = Router("123", List(Map("pinModel1"-> "Red", "pinModel2"-> "Black", "pinModel3"-> "Yellow")))
```

I would like the output to be:

```
val routers = List(("123","pinModel1","Red"),("123","pinModel2","Black"),("123","pinModel3","Yellow"))
```

The one way I could achieve it is to get the Router.modelInfo list and create that many Router instance. But, I believe that there must be a cleaner solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
val routers = 
  router.modelInfo.flatMap(_.map { case (key, value) => (router.routerId, key, value)})
```

Which yields:

```
(123,pinModel1,Red)
(123,pinModel2,Black)
(123,pinModel3,Yellow)
```

Comment: Thanks Yuval. This was helpful. Accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
for {
    m <- router.modelInfo
    (k, v) <- m
} yield (router.routerId, k, v)
```

(Which is really the same thing as Yuval's solution that just popped up.)

Comment: Even more concise :)